# xml-rpc multi thread client crash (c++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-memory, xml-rpc, variadic-functions

I am using xml-rpc, [release 1.41](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/change.html).

I am implementing a class to handle the xml-rpc connection. Each instance has a different xmlrpc_client to make calls to xml-rpc.

This is a code sample for calling the xml-rpc endpoint:

```
executeCommand(xmlrpc_value** ret, const string& methodName, const string& format, int numArgs, ...) {

  *ret = NULL;
  va_list args;

  xmlrpc_env env;
  xmlrpc_env_init(&env);
  xmlrpc_value* arg_list = NULL;
  const char* suffix = NULL;

  va_start(args, numArgs);
  xmlrpc_build_value_va(&env, format.c_str(), args, &arg_list,&suffix);
  xmlrpc_print_value(arg_list);
  va_end(args);

  if (!env.fault_occurred){
    if (*suffix != '\0')
    {
      xmlrpc_faultf(&env, "Junk after the argument ""specifier: '%s'.  ""There must be exactly one arument.", suffix);
    }
    else{
      xmlrpc_server_info* server = NULL;
      getActiveServerInfo(&server);

      CleanEnvAndReturnRV(env);
      xmlrpc_env_init(&env);
      xmlrpc_client_call2(&env, m_client, server, methodName.c_str(), arg_list, ret); // Both threads are making a successful call. 
    }
    xmlrpc_DECREF(arg_list);      // <<< **Crashes here **  
  } 
  return CleanEnvAndReturnRV(env);

}
```

It seems to me like each thread is creating its own xml-rpc values using xmlrpc_build_value_va, so no pointers are shared between the threads. 
Nonetheless, When two threads are calling this function, they crash when calling **xmlrpc_DECREF(arg_list);** because one or more of the refcounts are 0.

This is the back-trace from gdb:

> ## 0  0x00007ff814271107 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>
> (gdb) bt
>
> ## 0  0x00007ff814271107 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>
> ## 1  0x00007ff8142724e8 in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>
> ## 2  0x00007ff820977c07 in xmlrpc_abort_if_array_bad (arrayP=) at xmlrpc_array.c:43
>
> ## 3  0x00007ff820977c43 in xmlrpc_destroyArrayContents (arrayP=0x7ff7c382a080) at xmlrpc_array.c:64
>
> ## 4  0x00007ff820974f90 in destroyValue (valueP=0x7ff7c382a080) at xmlrpc_data.c:77
>
> ## 5  xmlrpc_DECREF (valueP=0x7ff7c382a080) at xmlrpc_data.c:155
>
> ## 6  0x00007ff820977c5e in xmlrpc_destroyArrayContents (arrayP=0x7ff80d49c860) at xmlrpc_array.c:69
>
> ## 7  0x00007ff820974f90 in destroyValue (valueP=0x7ff80d49c860) at xmlrpc_data.c:77
>
> ## 8  xmlrpc_DECREF (valueP=0x7ff80d49c860) at xmlrpc_data.c:155
>
> ## 9  0x00007ff81faa7fe8 in executeCommand(_xmlrpc_value**, std::string const&, std::string const&, int, ...) ()

From xmlrpc_array.c:

```
void xmlrpc_abort_if_array_bad(xmlrpc_value * const arrayP) {

    if (arrayP == NULL)
        abort();
    else if (arrayP->_type != XMLRPC_TYPE_ARRAY)
        abort();
    else {
        size_t const arraySize =
            XMLRPC_MEMBLOCK_SIZE(xmlrpc_value*, &arrayP->_block);
        xmlrpc_value ** const contents = 
            XMLRPC_MEMBLOCK_CONTENTS(xmlrpc_value*, &arrayP->_block);

        if (contents == NULL)
            abort();
        else {
            size_t index;

            for (index = 0; index < arraySize; ++index) {
                xmlrpc_value * const itemP = contents[index];
                if (itemP == NULL)
                    abort();
                else if (itemP->refcount < 1)  
                    abort(); // Line 43 . Aborts here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help understanding what makes this crash. Are there any shared pointers I am missing here? 
Am I wrong to assume none of the pointers are shared?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you making `m_client`. Are you using the Curl XML transport?

Comment: Yes, I am using the curl XML transport.